# Linux clustering over WAN links

Tags: linux, cluster, configuration-management

I am working on a project that would require the following : 
 - Central administration of multiple servers over multiple locations 
 - Secure connections between multiple locations 
 - Manage multiple servers configurations

**FACT**
There will be from 6 to around 30 hosts.
All OS are going to be 64bit Ubuntu 9.10.
Hosts are going to be in North America, Europe and India.

**What software(s) could I use to manage all hosts?**

**What software(s) could I use to manage and deploy configurations?**
I've looked at Chef, Puppet and Bcfg2.
Puppet and Chef look complex to deploy, considering the small number of hosts, is there a better way or best suited application to do this?

For securing connections, should I look for a SSH or VPN solution?

Comment: 6-30 hosts is not small!  It's too large to sensibly manage without puppet.  As far as configuring configuration goes, Puppet is by far one of the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet for deploying and management.
Securing - vpn + SeLinux (ssh as a de-facto).

To manage all hosts - what you mean?
Read logs? Rebooting? Full remote control?

May be RADIUS+LDAP as AAA?
Please, be concrete.

And what is "cluster" do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. <br>
I guess I will have to take a decision on the configuration management so I can define my needs better. After thinking about it, If I find a way to get all server on a private network (over WAN), this will lower my configuration needs and I could use bash/perl scripts to configure a new server (setup interfaces, private network, base packages) so it gets on the networks easily. <br>

I will continue reading on this, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I see.
So, I have about 20 servers over all world.

All what I need to do, I just do with VPN.
I have RADIUS+LDAP for authentication, authorization and accounting.
Its very easy for me as system administrator - I have only two servers (main and backup) with FreeRadius and OpenLDAP.
So, any new configuration or upgrading old is very simple with Puppet.

Example: new server in Germany-over IP KVM I set interface and ssh.
After all I start Puppet scripts here, from my home. After ~30 minutes I have new server with anything, what I need.

Answer (score 1):

To manage and deploy configurations, I suggest you look at [Cfengine 3](http://www.cfengine.org/), which is a configuration management solution that you didn't mention. It is extremely lightweight, and won't put too much overhead on a small-ish infrastructure of up to 30 servers.